# extjs combo:How to set user selected value as the default selected value next time?

Tags: extjs

In extjs combo box, I have this requirement: When the user selects an option from the combo, capture it, and next time page is loaded and combo is init-ed, set the value(both value and displayvalue) to the user's last selection.
I can get the user selected index by :`Combo.selectedIndex`, but how do we set this index back when the page loads next time?

Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very very rough but the way I would do it:

```
var comboStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    ...
    autoLoad: false,
    ...
});

var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    ...
    store: comboStore,
    ...
    listeners: {
       select: function() {
           ...use getValue() and save here...
       }
    }
});

comboStore.on("load",function() {
    ...load value here...
    combo.setValue(loaded value);
},this,{single: true});

comboStore.reload();
```

Comment: Can you please explain why we do :single: true

Comment: Single basically lets the listener fire only one. We do this because we only want to load the default once, when we first start.